# How can I read a HTML comment located outside of <html> using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a HTML comment outside of the DOM root node which I need to read:

```
<html>
   ... other stuff
</html>
<!-- The comment I want to read -->
```

Can I do this with JavaScript somehow?

Comment: They're actually HTML comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some testing on this and discovered that any HTML beyond **`</html>`** is appended to the **`<body>`** during parsing. So, in all browsers I tested (IE6/7, FF3, Opera10, Chrome2), the comment was accessible as **`document.body.lastChild`** and its contents can be retreived via **`document.body.lastChild.data`**.

Comment: Excellent work! I actually had an empty row at the end of my file so the document.body.lastChild.data was '\n', but by looking in firebug I see that the comment exists as a child node to body. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a generic solution.

Comment: Nice - using this technique with `document.firstChild` for comments *before* any other content.

Answer (score 2):

The DOM standard for the #document node (the logical root of a DOM document) allows exactly one element node (i.e. one <HTML>), but many comment nodes (and other, more esoteric node types). As such, we should expect

```
document.lastChild
```

to be the comment node you want in this instance. Oddly, *this does not work* (at least in Safari 4).

Putting a comment node before the HTML node is fine in my tests. In this case, document.childNodes.length is 2, and document.firstChild is the comment. Putting a comment after the HTML node seems to be inserted in the wrong place in the DOM - document.childNodes.length remains at 1, and the node in the DOM inspector is seen as the last child of the BODY node. However, I can't find that node using the DOM API at all!

This seems to be an oddity in (at least) the Safari implementation of DOM. A quick test using Firefox shows that it can't even find a comment node if it's the first entry in the document!

Edit: OK, as per  Aaron's comment and some more pondering, it's likely that the parser for the page is just discarding the nodes during parsing. I'm no longer certain this is a bug, but I can't find anything in the (XML) spec that allows parsers to discard entire comment nodes - only their textual content.

Comment: The standard allows several comments but most XML/HTML parsers don't put them in the DOM. It's not a bug since the standard doesn't require them to do it.

Comment: those comments are mainly for the parser ... doctype etc?

Comment: A doctype is not a comment (and uses different syntax). Comments are purely for humans, but *should* be preserved during parsing, imo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin for this problem: 
http://www.bennadel.com/index.cfm?dax=blog:1563.view

It seems that

```
objChildNode.nodeType === 8
```

is the point!